# Does there exits an simple algorithm to calculate and update LLR for nand flash memory?

Tags: signal-processing

I'm workding on nand flash DSP(Digital Signal Processing) now, and encounter obstacle, which is: how to generate and update LLR LUT for TLC and QLC nand flash memory? any suggestion or reference will be very useful! thanks!

I've tried in MLC case, but it performance is poor, maybe the method I'am used is mistake;

Comment: try https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ or https://physics.stackexchange.com/